# android Why is my RelativeLayout not working

Tags: android, xml, layout

Beginner question here!
look at picture,
I want the butten-edittext-button to fill the width of the screen.
The space to type text is to small.
Any ides?
(been searching and testing for 3 hour)

[image]

here is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Gallery xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:id="@+id/examplegallery" 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/InnerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnNewPen" 
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/edittextaddtext" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pen"
        />      
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextaddtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnsave"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/btnsave" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="save"
        />
   </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnNewPen" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pen"
    />      
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittextaddtext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/btnsave"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnNewPen"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
    />
```

Leaving the rest as it is.

Comment: thanks that was nice. Next thing to do is put one button above "save" and one button above "pen", same size and the gallery above should be under this two buttons. That is i dont want the two B to push the gallery up

Comment: You can use FrameLayout to make elements 'hover' above another view. Like [here](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-%E2%80%93-layouts-part-three-frame-layout-and-scroll-view/)